# PowerBIEmbed with loggedin user authorization

Tags: reactjs, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am developing one react application to show power bi reports on one of my app pages.

i am using ['powerbi-client-react'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react) npm client to include the report by giving the report URL. But previously I was using my dev account to see the embedded powerbi. But once i go for live testing, the clients can't see their reports because I was using **accessTokenKey** from my dev account statically.

Now I wanted it to work for all of my customers with their login and show their reports inside my app.

What i need to do to implement the autorization to show powerbi report?

Answer (score 1):

> What i need to do to implement the autorization to show powerbi report?

- *For using embed power Bi for your customers or for your organization you can use either Azure AD token or Embed token.*
- *In rest api you need to have Azure AD token. which will expire for every hour.*
- *For the customers Azure AD token is used to generate Embed token.*
- *While using Embed Tokens you need to specify which content can the customer access and also their access level.*
- *Here are the authentication flows for [embed token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-tokens?tabs=embed-for-customers#authentication-flows) generation for customers.*
- *Below image represents the authentication flows of Embed token for your customers.*

[image]

- *Refer this Microsoft Document for complete information regarding Embed Token for customers.*
  *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-tokens?tabs=embed-for-customers#embed-token*

Comment: Thanks for this information. I will try this and update if it working or not. :thumsup: